# Connecting centre of ellipses with lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to connect centre of ellipses with lines. THis is what I have-
[image]

Here is the `XAML` code-

```
<Grid x:Name="Main" Background="#FFF9F9F9">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <Grid x:Name="Start" Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF0D3A7C">         
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="End" Grid.Row="2" Background="#FF0D3A7C">            
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="Game" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF0D3A7C">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,20,20,20" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,5.849"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,20,20,20" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,5.849"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20,20,20,20" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,5.849"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,20,20,20" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,5.849"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,20,20,20" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,5.849"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20,20,20,20" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,5.849"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,20,20,20" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,5.849"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,20,20,20" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,5.849"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20,20,20,20" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,5.849"/>      
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Now I want to connect a `line` or `checkbox` from centre of each ellipse to all the ellipses using `C#`. Basically I will have a button and upon clicking it, I want all the lines to appear. I am new to app development and am not sure how to go about it.

**Edit-**
Basically I want to connect the centres of each nodes to all the rest. THis is similar to the following figure where I have done it for the first node manually-

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you want to achieve. Ellipses have each 2 focal points, not just one center. Can you mock up a drawing where you show how you would expect it to look? Also, what did you do to solve the problem yourself? What is it that you don't understand exactly?

Comment: Please see the edit. Using `XAML` I can  manually connect the centres but I dont know how to do that using C#

Comment: @KarmaEDV Ellipses have 2 focal points (or 1 if its a circle) but they only have 1 centre (which is the midpoint between the 2 focal points).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number of ellipsis stays the same and that you know which one is which where. Also, this is a quick & dirty explanation.

Start by giving each ellipsis a name

```
<Ellipse Name="ETopLeft" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
Margin="20,20,20,20" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,5.849"/>
```

In the Code Behind get the current X/Y position of all ellipsis at runtime with this and add half the lenght/height to get all centers

```
Point posETopLeft = ETopLeft.TransformToAncestor(MainWindow)
                          .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
posETopLeft.X += (ETopLeft.Width / 2)
posETopLeft.Y += (ETopLeft.Height / 2)
```

Now add lines dynamically to the form, rinse and repeat according to your logic/requirements.

```
var myLine = new Line();
myLine.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;

myLine.X1 = CenterPointETopLeft.X;
myLine.X2 = CenterPointETopMiddle.X;
myLine.Y1 = CenterPointETopLeft.Y;
myLine.Y2 = CenterPointETopMiddle.Y;

Canvas.Children.Add(myLine);
```

This is not everything, and you'll end up with many repetition, but I think it'll be a good exercise for you to figure out how to make it really work and more elegant.

Comment: Thanks but it gives me following error-
`Error 1 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Ellipse' does not contain a definition for 'TransformToAncestor' and no extension method 'TransformToAncestor' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Ellipse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

`Error 4 The name 'CenterPointETopLeft' does not exist in the current context `